# stringr equivalent to grep

Tags: r, stringr

Is there an *stringr* equivalent to base R's `grep` function?

I want to have the index of the string that matches. Example:

```
grep("F|Y", LETTERS)
[1]  6 25
```

With *stringr* my workaround would be using `which` as follows:

```
which(str_detect(LETTERS, "F|Y"))
[1]  6 25
```

Comment: I don't use stringr, but see if `str_locate` is what you need.

Comment: `str_locate` returns a matrix of start/end columns.  I think the OP is looking for the index without using `which`

Comment: @akrun yes. Thats what i am looking for

Comment: As the man pages for `stringr` are quite clear and unambiguous, there's no doubt that none of the functions return just the indices.  So (as us DataMungerGuru Accolytes always ask),  *why* do you want to do this?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am porting my code from base R to _stringr_. As this is my first time using _stringr_ i dont want to start with using wrong functions. Thats why i am asking here...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer but it might be helpful for future visitors:

Now you can use `str_which(string, pattern)` which is a wrapper around `which(str_detect(string, pattern))` and equivalent to `grep(pattern, string)`.

```
str_which(LETTERS, "F|Y")
[1]  6 25
```

More details at: http://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_subset.html

Answer (score -1):

With the new update string_like will also be applicable.

`which(str_like(LETTERS, "F|Y"))`

Read more about the [stringr updates](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/12/stringr-1-5-0/) that are linked below.
Hope this helps everyone.